# Find the first three terms of the sequence

Tags: mathematics, knowledge, number-sequence

Find the missing values in the sequence:

> $X, X, X, 59, 2, 65, 3, 58, 9, 79, 3, 23$

Hint 1:

> There are no mathematical links between the numbers. In other words, the numbers are not interconnected to each other through a formula/algorithm.

Hint 2:

> All the numbers combined without the commas form a very special number :)

Comment: To the couple of guys that were here before me: Downvoting a puzzle without dropping a comment is not very constructive. If you feel that a puzzle isn't very good, please at least explain why, so OP has a chance to improve. (Also, this looks like a perfectly plausible number sequence problem, and the sequence doesn't seem to be on OEIS either, so either I'm missing something crucial, or the random downvote fairies are being very partial today.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it is

> $\pi$

which

> we write it as $1$ digit, $2$ digits, $1$ digit, $2$ digits, and so on

so the answer is

> $3,14,1$